# Helm init connection timeout spotty

Tags: docker, deployment, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-helm

So when I run helm init, sometimes it works and a tiller pod gets created and sometimes the connection times out. I reasoned to extend the tiller-connection-time out with:

`helm init --tiller-connection-timeout 500 --service-account tiller --tiller-image my-image --tiller-namespace my-namespace`

..but I got this error:
**Error: unknown flag: --tiller-connection-timeout**

However, the docs list this as a valid flag, copy-pasted from the docs:
https://docs.helm.sh/helm/

Anybody else have issues with `helm init` in Kubernetes? How to get a consistent tiller pod created? I'm happy to provide more info, if that helps

Answer (score 3):

`--tiller-connection-timeout` is available from helm 2.9.0, take a look at your helm version, it maybe need some upgrade.